# Using Jquery and AJAX to pass parameters to VB.NET webmethod

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

I've been searching the internet for hours trying to pass parameters to my code behind using JQUERY $.ajax. I've tried a ton of different things, but nothing has worked. When I don't pass any parameters and set the vb.net function to not receive parameters the functions will get called. But once I try adding parameters, the function never gets called.

Client Side:

```
$("#<%=saveResource2.clientID %>").click(function() {
        var parDesc = $("#<%=ddlPDesc.clientID %> option:selected").text();
        $("#<%=Button1.clientID %>").click();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Projects.aspx/btnSaveResource",
            data: JSON.stringify({Desc: parDesc}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {

                $("#<%=lblPerson.clientID %>").text(msg);
                // Do something interesting here.
            }
        });

    });
```

Server Side:

> ```
> <WebMethod()> _
> <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
> Public Shared Function btnSaveResource(ByVal parDesc As String) As String
>     Dim d As String = parDesc
>     Return d + "test"
>  End Function
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing from this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({Desc: parDesc}),
```

To

```
data: JSON.stringify({parDesc: parDesc}),
```

Comment: Hahahaha, wow. That was it. I didn't realize that the variable the function accepted had the have the exact same name as what was being passed. I didn't even consider that. Thanks!

Comment: @Weston, did you consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad, Yep I did consider it. In fact my question was answered so quickly that I still had to wait 7 minutes before I was allowed to accept it. I've done it now.