# Infinite scroll Sql statement to get next records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do infinite scroll in my .NET website, using javascript and the following sql statement (sql server 2008). This sql gets the first 10 rows, but my javascript causes the sql to execute each time the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, and each time, it pulls the same (first 10) records, but I want it to pull the NEXT 10 records, each time user scrolls to the bottom. How do I use this sql and row_number to get the NEXT 10 rows, each time user scrolls to bottom of page?

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) As RowNum, 
  * From Topic) As a 
WHERE RowNum 
BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

       function lastPostFunc() {
           $('#divPostsLoader').html('<img src="images/bigLoader.gif">');

           //send a query to server side to present new content
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Default.aspx/Foo",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {

                   if (data != "") {
                       $('.divLoadData:last').after(data.d);
                   }
                   $('#divPostsLoader').empty();
               }

           })
       };

       //When scroll down, the scroller is at the bottom with the function below and fire the lastPostFunc function
       $(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
               lastPostFunc();
           }
       });

    });
</script>
```

I now have the above sql in stored procedure:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function Foo() As String
    Dim strConn As String = "Data Source="
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand("InfiniteScroll", conn)
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
    Dim DS As New DataSet()
    DA.Fill(DS, "RefologyForumTopic")
    Dim getPostsText As New StringBuilder()
    Dim dv As DataView = DS.Tables(0).DefaultView

    For Each myDataRow As DataRowView In dv
        getPostsText.AppendFormat("price: {0}</br>", myDataRow("Topic"))
        getPostsText.AppendFormat("description: {0}</br></p>", myDataRow("UserID"))
    Next

    getPostsText.AppendFormat("<div style='height:15px;'></div>")
    Return getPostsText.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't the *next* 10 rows be `BETWEEN 11 and 20`?

Comment: You are correct, but how do I write THIS sql statement so it pulls 11 and 20?, then when user scrolls down again, between 21 and 30, etc.?

Comment: @mlg74 -- can you use stored procedures?  if so, see my answer below.  good luck.

Comment: @mlg74 - On the client, you'd store the highest row you loaded.  When you go to load more rows, pass in that high value as a parameter, and increment it by 10.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I wish i knew how to do that...

Comment: @sgeddes I am working on trying your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically we do this using a stored procedure passing in a page and/or result counter parameters.  Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) As RowNum, * 
   FROM Topic) As a 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1+(@recsPerPage)*(@page-1) AND @recsPerPage*(@page)
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58920/27).

--EDIT

This is all untested, but should get you going in the right direction:

First, add a hidden page to the page to store your current page number:

```
<input type=hidden id=hidPage name=hidPage value="1">
```

Second, update your data parameters in your ajax call:

```
data: { Page: $("#hidPage").value() },
```

Third, update your web method to accept the param:

```
Public Shared Function Foo(page as string (or int -- would need to test for sure)) As String
```

Then update your SQL to pass the parameter.  I'm not going to rewrite that, but use this link for assistance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.71).aspx

And finally, reset your hidPage variable on your ajax success handler.

```
var newPage = parseInt($("#hidPage").val());
$("#hidPage").val(newPage+1);
```

Good luck.

Comment: How do we pass parameters @recsPerPage+1, @Page-1, etc?

Comment: Might be helpful to see your js and backend code to help with that.  But essentially, you need to create a stored procedure (vs running SQL directly) which accepts 2 parameters (recsperpage and page). On your webpage, store the page variable in a hidden field and increment after each call.  Just trying to get you going in the right direction :-)

Comment: I appreciate the help. I need to figure out how to store variable in hidden field.

Comment: i inserted my javascript above

Comment: I'm looking at the SQL Fiddle and if I set: SET "@recsPerPage = 3
SET @page = 3", then it only returns row 8 and 9. Do you know why? It should return 7, 8 and 9, right?

Comment: If I add "data: { Page: $("#hidPage").value() }," and/or "Public Shared Function Foo(page as string)" and/or "Public Shared Function Foo(page as integer), the sql doesn't return anything. I just get my spinning gif as if it is retrieving data forever.

Comment: In regards to the fiddle, I fixed it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58920/27 -- I had the +1 inside of the parentheses accidentally.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for updating the SQL, now that works, the only problem I am having is the data parameters of the Ajax. If I put anything in the data parameters, the sql doesn't fire. If I leave it blank, as I have it in my question, the sql fires, but doesn't pass the parameter.

Comment: The SQL doesn't fire or Foo doesn't fire?  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351301/using-jquery-and-ajax-to-pass-parameters-to-vb-net-webmethod

Comment: I figured out why the Data parameter didn't work, it was because it needed to be data: { Page: $("#hidPage").val() }, NOT data: { Page: $("#hidPage").value() },

Comment: Actually, I had to do this for data: data: JSON.stringify({ Page: $("#hidPage").val() }),

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the previously selected rows.
In order to do this, you need to create a history table where you insert the previously selected records.

So, if the `topic` table has a primary key on a column, let's call the column `topic_id`, and the history table is called `hist_topic` with primary key on column `topic_id`, your need to query the first 10 records from the `topic` table that are not found in the `hist_topic` table.

After reading the data, just insert the selected `topic_id` values in the `hist_topic`. This can be fast done using bulk insert.

Before first query, you need to empty the table of previous results so that you will not get false positives.

In order to handle multiple users you need to extend the history table with an additional field, `session`, numeric, that will contain a unique number, generated for each page load. As you are using AJAX, you need not worry about passing this unique id from one page to the other. The unique id can be generated by calling an additional script on page load.

This will help you also in the case that new records are added while you are querying.

The steps should be like this:
page load
 - generate unique id
query

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime) As RowNum, 
  * From Topic) As a 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HIST_TOPIC B WHERE A.TOPIC_ID = B.TOPIC_ID AND B.SESSION = @SESSION);
```

insert into history 
  - use bulk insert

Cleaning up the inserted values can be done on the `onunload` event of the `body`.

One of the most important advantages is that you will not lose records using this approach. Let's consider the approach where the page is kept at client level. Imagine having the following records:

```
id   |   some_number   |  some_text
------------------------------------
1    |   1             |    text1
2    |   4             |    text4
3    |   9             |    text9
4    |   10            |    text10
5    |   19            |    text19
```

and let's suppose you ask for the first 5 records and you have an order by clause on some_number, ascending.

`select * from topic where RowNum BETWEEN (@recsPerPage+1)*(@page-1) AND @recsPerPage*(@page) order by some_number`

`@recsPerPage = 5`

Then the system gets a new record

`6        11                text11`

On the next query, because the new records will be the new number 5, the query will bring you, again, the record you have seen in the first page:

`5        19                text19`

LE:
I am not experienced with .NET web applications, as I work in Java, therefore i can only give you an example in my world and maybe you can translate it.

**Bulk insert**

As regarding bulk insert, i found this link for [bulk insert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx)

**Generate unique id on page load**

I do not know how to do in .NET web applications, but i give you a hint about how i would do it in Java web application, using JSP. In JSP the java code (placed in a servlet) is executed first, then the html is generated. Thus, if i add at the beginning a servlet, it will be executed when the page is loaded.

```
<% long uniqueId = UniqueIdGeneration.getUniqueId();%>
```

The `uniqueId` is a `long` variable that will be available throughout the page, whenever i am within a scriptlet. The `getUniqueId` method will return the time in milliseconds. You should make it sleep one millisecond before returning the result in order to make sure only unique numbers are generated.

**Unload page**

Use the `onunload` event of the `body`.

```
<javascript>
function doUnload() {
  var session=<%=uniqueId%>;
  //use the new session variable to pass it to the server using AJAX. The server will respond by deleting the records corresponding to it.
}
</javascript>
```

Comment: `-1` - Storing the previously selected rows in a table is just overly complicating the problem, not to mention makes resetting this data when the user leaves the page near impossible.  The range should be kept track of by the client.

Comment: I am using this approach very successful for a table that on average has around 2 million records and the maximum possible could reach 10 mil.
It is very easy to store the previously selected elements and resetting the data is done when the query is initialized again.

Not to mention the fact that keeping track of pages at the client's level can lead to interesting results if, for instance, you need to scroll through pages, you could get different results on the same page number, depending on the operation on the table, whereas my approach can be easily extended to include page numbers.

Comment: I'm fine with alternative designs, but I think you should explain the whole architecture in your answer.  Including initialization, handling multiple *anonymous* users, etc.  If you elaborate on your design, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @GeorgeVremescu can you give me an example on how to bulk insert into history table and making unique session variable on page load? And how to "unload" on the event body to clean up when user leaves page? Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeVremescu, sorry I am not advanced enough to be able to do that stuff. Thank you for trying. I'm sure it works, but need more help I guess.

Comment: Remember it for later on. When you are advanced enough, you can also judge it and, should you come up with a different solution, a better one, a simpler one, please share!